# Unity Firebase ValueChanged

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to receive the data from firebase with this code in Unity:

```
public void Start()
{
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://unity-f82f6.firebaseio.com");

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;


    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Leaders").ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;


}

void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    Debug.Log(args.Snapshot);
}
```

And I want it to tell me the new value of "Leaders" when it changes, however it only triggers once and I cannot find a solution that will make it run multiple times.

Comment: Your `HandleValueChanged` should be called: right away with the current value of `Leaders` from the database, and then whenever something changes under `Leaders`. If the latter doesn't happen for you, can you explain how you test this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to change:(on my project works ok)

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Leaders").ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
```

with:

```
reference.GetReference("Leaders").ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
```